# Symfony3, taking user input and saving into mysql

Tags: mysql, symfony

I am new to symfony and open-source in general. Im trying to create a simple product submition page which would store product's information in mysql. So far I've only been able to hard-code all the information and successfully store it (this was my first task to achieve). This is the code for it:

```
public function createAction()
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->setName('Keyboard');
        $product->setPrice(15.50);
        $product->setDescription('Logitech keyboard v2.00');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);

        $em->flush();

        return new Response("Saved new product with: " .$product->getId() ."Id");
    }
```

Now I want to have a page with couple text boxes and to be able to take this information, validate it and then store it. What would be a clever way to do it? As I'm learning for my internship, I want to be able to do it in a best possible way. Are twig templates the best solution here? What about fetching user's input? I would be really thankful if someone could write step-by-step bullet points on how to achieve my goal in abstract sentences. Thank you and have a great remaining Friday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** One of the best and yet simple ways for you to start your mission would be by reading Symfony book chapter about [Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html). It contains basic examples about form rendering, validation and submission using twig.

**2)** If you need to know more about how to save everything to database and would like to use Doctrine (most common way) then [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) chapter covers it in detail and is also not too deep to make it easy enough.

**3)** If you would like to deepen your understanding of Validation then you should definitely [read](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) about it too

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html